# puppeteer writing in the label doesn't work pop up

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm creating a bot to enter the site.

After opening the popup I have 2 fields, `emailAddress` and `password`. Both have random id and only `name` value.

The `emailAddress` is not completing. But the `password` works normally(completing).

This is a part my code

```
//open poupup

await page.$eval( '#anchor-open', form => form.click() );

//wait for the screen to load

await page.waitForSelector('input[name="emailAddress"]');

//write in the fields

await page.type('input[name="emailAddress"]', '22@d.com', {delay: 100});

await page.type('input[name="password"]', '****************', {delay: 100});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you provide the site url to can test it

Comment: code  available on https://pastebin.com/tcpj0CE4

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for [domcontentloaded](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#event-domcontentloaded) event. then wait for `#anchor-acessar` element before click it.

The code below working fine with me.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.nike.com.br", {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });

  await page.waitForSelector('#anchor-acessar');

  await page.$eval("#anchor-acessar", (form) => form.click());

  await page.waitForSelector('input[name="emailAddress"]');

  await page.type('input[name="emailAddress"]', "22@d.com", { delay: 100 });

  await page.type('input[name="password"]', "****************", { delay: 100 });

  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

  // await browser.close();
})();
```